# Launchctl error on mac os

Tags: mac

I have a script to be started at boot. Script was loaded into lauchd using launchctl load ...

Error I have in the logs:

```
Apr 17 14:02:07 win com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[158] (my.script[184]): Exited with exit code: 1
```

That script needs root privs to be able to function, and from what I read on interweb launchd gives root at the time of launch. Starting script after boot up manually works 100%

It exits with code 1, how do I find more info what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Did you write that script yourself? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

`launchd` will run launch jobs in your personal folder using your own user privileges. It's only `root` in `/Library/` and `/System/Library`.

See [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/36087/how-do-i-run-a-launchd-command-as-root).