# How can normal user run passwd Command on Linux ..with out being a root user

Tags: linux

Can you advise over it..this was question for me to check but was not able to get this ...if the group can help.. can you advise.. my question is clear that we should not be root or root user to do that

Comment: have you tried "man passwd"?

Comment: See also [Can I make a script always execute as root?](https://superuser.com/q/440363/150988) and/or [How to run a program as root without “sudo”?](https://superuser.com/q/290903/150988)

Comment: … or go to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and search for setuid.

Comment: @SolarMike: The question makes it fairly clear that the OP understands *that* a normal user can run ``passwd``.  I don’t see anything in the man page that explains *how* that’s possible.

Comment: I believe SUID will help..

Answer (score 2):

The `passwd` utility has the [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit set. It means that it will be run as **root**.

```
$ ls -lh /usr/bin/passwd 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 53K May 17 01:37 /usr/bin/passwd
```

So this utility will be able to modify the `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` files, which are owned by `root`.

As it is written in the man page,

> A normal user may only change the password for his/her own account

Programs using the `setuid` bit should be really carefully designed, since running as root is a real security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Any user can run `passwd` to change their **own** password.

Comment: ... but ... *how?*

Comment: setuid  See the other answer

Comment: ***I know that*** — see my comments on the question.   My point is that the question the question asks *How?* and your post doesn’t answer that.